# What's the word for a segment/part of a spectrum chart?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say there's a spectrum chart (or any chart) like this:[image]

and I want to point out that 300-400 MHz segment is exceeding the red line.
Then what is the correct word I should use for those segment/range/part?

For example, I want to write some sentences like "The test failed due to 300-400 [word].", "300-400 [word] exceeded the criteria." or "300-400 [word] is exceedingly high". Also, I'd like to know the word when it's not a range but a specific point, for example, to point out 300 [word] being the highest.

Comment: Band or sub-band, depending on the width.

Comment: It’s a section. Define it and then use “this section” to refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any term that applies to any spectral chart, but this is apparently the result of a radiated emissions test for electromagnetic compliance. In this case we can say,

- The test failed due to emissions between 300 and 400 MHz.
- Emissions exceeded the test limits between 300 and 400 MHz.
- 300 to 400 MHz radiated emissions are exceedingly high.

For the case where " it's not a range but a specific point, for example, to point out 300 [word] being the highest", you could say,

- Peak emissions were observed at 300 MHz.

More informally, you might just say,

- The highest peak was at 300 MHz.

**Edit**

The term *band* was offered up in the comments, and this could probably be used in many instances. But in my experience a *band* is more often a range of frequencies that's defined according to an application (for example "Ka-band radar" or the "10-meter amateur radio band") rather than one defined in reference to an experimental result.

Answer (score 0):

In the paper [How large a vocabulary is needed for reading and listening?](https://www.lextutor.ca/cover/papers/nation_2006.pdf), Nation (the author's name is Nation) divides each segment with 1000 words families. For the range of 5000 word families to 6000 word families, he calls it as "the 6th 1000 word families".

[image]